# Select next occurence in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
  <a href="#vegeta" class="active"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#goku"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#gohan"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#shenron"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

How can I select next link after active class using jQuery (#goku in this case)?

Comment: `.next()` ? https://api.jquery.com/next/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.active').closest('li').next().find('a');
```

The "next" element is a sibling of the li, not the element that has the active class on it.

```js
console.log(
  $('.active').closest('li').next().find('a').get()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
  <a href="#vegeta" class="active"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#goku"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#gohan"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#shenron"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```